# Error when I added a data object inside my JSON Parser

Tags: android, json, compiler-errors

I can't seem to figure out why and how to solve this error I am getting on line: 

**MovieItem item = new MovieItem();** 

It says MovieItem() in MovieItem cannot be applied to: 

**Expected Parameters: id: String, title: String, overView: String, releaseDate: String, rating: String, posterPath: String, url: String. 

Actual Arguments: .**

```
 private ArrayList<MovieItem> getMovieJsonObject(String movieJSONObject) throws JSONException {

        final String m_Result = "results";
        final String m_ID = "id";
        final String m_Title = "title";
        final String m_Release = "release_date";
        final String m_Vote = "vote_average";
        final String m_Overview = "overview";
        final String m_Poster = "poster_path";

        ArrayList<MovieItem> movieItems = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject movieJSON = new JSONObject(movieJSONObject);
        JSONArray movieInformation = movieJSON.getJSONArray(m_Result);

        for (int i = 0; i < movieInformation.length(); i++) {
            MovieItem item = new MovieItem();
            JSONObject result_movie = movieInformation.getJSONObject(i);
            movieId[i] = result_movie.getString(m_ID);
            movieTitle[i] = result_movie.getString(m_Title);
            moviePath[i] = result_movie.getString(m_Poster);
            moviePlot[i] = result_movie.getString(m_Overview);
            movieRating[i] = result_movie.getString(m_Vote);
            movieReleaseDate[i] = result_movie.getString(m_Release);
            movieItems.add(item);
        }
        return movieItems;
    }


public class MovieItem {

private String id;
private String title;
private String overView;
private String releaseDate;
private String rating;
private String posterPath;
private String url;

public MovieItem(String id, String title, String overView, String releaseDate, String rating, String posterPath, String url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.overView = overView;
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.posterPath = posterPath;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getTitle() { return title; }

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getOverView() {
    return overView;
}

public void setOverView(String overView) {
    this.overView = overView;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getPosterPath() {
    return posterPath;
}

public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
    this.posterPath = posterPath;
}
```

Comment: why you are not using set method from the pojo to set the variable into items .

Comment: Sidenot: take a look at GSON or Moshi or even Jackson for that matter. Parsing JSON yourself is boilerplate code that can easily be eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your constructor :

```
        JSONObject result_movie = movieInformation.getJSONObject(i);
        MovieItem item = new MovieItem(result_movie.getString(m_ID),
        result_movie.getString(m_Title),
        result_movie.getString(m_Overview),
        result_movie.getString(m_Release),
        result_movie.getString(m_Vote),
        result_movie.getString(m_Poster),
        "url"
       );

        movieItems.add(item);
```

Comment: Quick question, what is "url" suppose to be? The url to launch the website?

Comment: Check your json parser , is your class :) I put "url" because you didnt parse that value